# Array from queryselector and eventlistener issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

Faced with the things that I can't understand how to manage with elements statements, like toggling classes with event listeners. The code below shows buttons with click event, which adds the class and if other had this class it removes it. But each time the last one button doesn't react on that event. Can anyone explain me why and how to handle it?

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
Array.from(buttons).forEach(function(el, i){
 el.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  
  for(let val of buttons) {
   console.log(val)
   if(val.classList.contains('red')){
       val.classList.remove('red');
   } else {
       el.classList.add('red');
      }
  }  
 })
})
```

```css
.red {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
```

And is there a better way to handle this classes toggling via pure JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did some mistake in your if-else statement code:

here, I correct it:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
Array.from(buttons).forEach(function(el, i){
 el.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  
  for(let val of buttons) {
   if(val.classList.contains('red')){
       val.classList.remove('red');
   }
                el.classList.add('red');
          console.log(val)
  }  
 })
})
```

```css
.red {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
```

Hope, it will work for you. Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the `if - else`? What did you change in the `if - else`, except where the `console.log` is?

Comment: yes, it works... but what was wrong with else condition... and why always the last one element doesnt react on that condition ?

Comment: @HassanImam yes you removed it, but that doesn't change anything really.

Comment: @caramba, actually it helps. But dont get the issue with the last one element. Why its not working correct.

Comment: @NeedHate Well, your condition was to add red class to clicked button and remove the red class from any other button. But, in case a button doesn't have red class, your code was adding red class to it, which was later getting removed, if the button is later in the array, its red class will be removed. I hope, I have explained myself.

Answer (score 2):

So you wan't to add the class "red" to the one you clicked and removed it from all other right?

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

Array.from(buttons).forEach(function(x){
 x.addEventListener('click', function(b){   
  unsetRed();
  b.srcElement.classList.add('red');
 })
})

function unsetRed(){
 [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button.red'), function(x) {
  x.classList.remove('red');
 });
}
```

```css
.red {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: I think its doing the same with other way. )

Comment: @Werner This is better solution to the above problem. Clear too! Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

So first just to show, the code you had a little shortened. It does not exactly what you want (will show that in next snippet). But what it does is almost what you want. On click it toggles the class red. The missing part is, it doesn't toggle all the other buttons.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(function(element){
 element.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    if(element.classList.contains('red')){
       element.classList.remove('red');
   } else {
       element.classList.add('red');
    }
 });
});
```

```css
.red {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
```

So some explanation will be found in the code. But first of all. Do never toggle classes like `red` but toggle classes saying something like `active`. Why? Because if your client wants to change that to green you only need to change your `CSS` and not the JS. If you compare the code to the code above there is not a lot of difference. Except we do some more stuff before adding the class active which is removing all active classes.

This is just to give you an idea how to `handle` and `fire` events. You can do lots more with that. Like also passing arguments, elements or what ever you need. To get and react on the right stuff...

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
        if(element.classList.contains('active')){
            element.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
            // this is like: "Fire event on the document"
            document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('toggle-all-my-buttons', {}));
            element.classList.add('active');
        }
    });
});

// here we listen on the document and can react if it gets fired no matter from where
document.addEventListener('toggle-all-my-buttons', function(){
    console.log('toggle all my buttons');
    buttons.forEach(function(element){
        element.classList.remove('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
```

[Read more about CustomEvents here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

Comment: thanks for explanations. Just used .red to be obvious of what I am doing. But isnt it more simplier not to create a custom event ?

Comment: @NeedHate well yes, let's say of course. But, if you get used to use events it's not a big deal either. Also it's very obvious what is does and it's super maintainable. Like if your application gets bigger, and something changes the state of your button it's so easy. Just listen on the event, fire the event and voilà. I guess the biggest deal is to figure out good names for all the custom events. Cause if you fire them on the document you can only use them once

Comment: I've accepted the answer from @Hassan Imam, but took into a count your answer too. It was very useful. Thanks!